# Встроенные покупки Android

Tags: android, in-app-purchases, android-billing

Все делаю по документации:
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Integrating_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_into_an_Android_Application_%E2%80%93_A_Tutorial

Но при попытке купить какой либо товар мне выдает - "Необходимо войти в аккаунт Google", хотя я уже авторизован в аккаунте Google.

В чем возможна проблема? Кэш у Play Market очищал.

Comment: Вы не по документации делаете а по устаревшему туториалу. Также убедитесь, что у вас версия приложения подписана релизным ключом. И вы не пытаетесь сделать покупку с аккаунта на коий зареган аккаунт разработчика.

Comment: Подписал релизным ключем, запустил под другим пользователем. Создал контент для продажи, все вроде бы как надо. Но при попытке купить выдает ошибку - "Этот продукт не продается", хотя я завел его в консоле разработчика и он активен.

Comment: Других предложений кроме как переделать всё с нуля по офиц. документации у меня нет. Единственное, помню, была у меня похожая ошибка в случае, когда версия приложения на девайсе и в маркете отличались (типа 1.0 vs 1.1)

Comment: Все сделал по инструкции от google. Получаю JSON с товаром. Запускаю Intent на покупку и он тоже мне возвращает ошибку - "Этот товар не продается" :(

Comment: В моём случае такое было если я под акком разработчика пытался это делать и/или если не совпадала версия приложения в маркете и на устройстве и/или не релизным ключом подписано. Ещё, может быть надо залить в маркет бета-версию apk, в коем уже встроены покупки, подождать пару часов пока оно опубликуется и проверить, что второй ваш акк указан в списке бета-тестеров в консоли.

Comment: Я создал второй товар. Самое интересное, что я подписал приложение, выложил как бетта тестирование. Запустил с совершенно другого телефона, первый товар стал покупаться, а второй выдает такую же ошибку - "Необходимо войти в Google аккаунт." Возможно стоит подождать и товар проидексируется, не возможно так, что один товар можно купить, а второй нельзя. подождем.

Comment: Ну да, возможно надо немного подождать)